# Merge-Sort Algorithm. Merge function does not work

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, merge, mergesort

I am trying to do a Merge-Sort algorithm and I ran into a block with the merge function. I have tried several different ways of trying to fix this and followed several YouTube tutorials, but it still does not work.

Could somebody please help me figure out what's wrong with this?

#### mergeSort

```
void mergeSort(int arrayToSort[], int startIndex, int lengthToSort) {

    int midIndex = 0;

    if (startIndex < lengthToSort) { // if base case not reached
        int midIndex = (startIndex + lengthToSort) / 2;
        mergeSort(arrayToSort, startIndex, midIndex);
        mergeSort(arrayToSort, (midIndex + 1), lengthToSort);
        merge(arrayToSort, startIndex, lengthToSort);
    }
}
```

### Merge

```
void merge(int arraySortedInTwoHalves[], int startIndex, int length) {

    int size = (length - startIndex) + 1;
    int padding = 0;

    if (size % 2 > 0) (padding = 1);

    int *temp = new int[size];

    int left = size / 2;
    int right = (size / 2) + padding;

    int i = 0;
    int j = (size / 2) + padding;
    int k = 0;

    while ((i < left) && (j < length)) {

        if (arraySortedInTwoHalves[i] <= arraySortedInTwoHalves[j]) {
            temp[k] = arraySortedInTwoHalves[i];
            i++;
        }
        else {
            temp[k] = arraySortedInTwoHalves[j];
            j++;
        }
        k++;
        while (i < left) {
            temp[k] = arraySortedInTwoHalves[i];
            k++;
        }
        while (j < length) {
            temp[k] = arraySortedInTwoHalves[j];
            j++;
        }
    }
}
```

### Main

```
int main() {

    // setup an array of random numbers of size n
    const int arrSize = 50;
    int nums[arrSize];

    for (int i = 0; i <= arrSize; i++) {
        nums[i] = rand() % arrSize;
    }

    mergeSort(nums, 0, arrSize-1);

    for (int i = 0; i < arrSize; i++) {
        std::cout << nums[i] << " ";
    }

    return(0);
}
```

### Solution

Here's a complete solution I made, just in case it is helpful to anybody else...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <ctime>

void mergeSort(int arrayToSort[], int startIndex, int lengthToSort);
void merge(int arraySortedInTwoHalves[], int startIndex, int length);

int main() {

    // setup an array of random numbers of size n
    const int arrSize = 10000;
    int nums[arrSize];

    for (int i = 0; i <= arrSize; i++) {
        nums[i] = rand() % arrSize;
    }

    // just a timer to measure performance
    int start_s = clock();

    mergeSort(nums, 0, arrSize-1);

    for (int i = 0; i < arrSize; i++) {
        std::cout << nums[i] << " ";
    }

    // stop timer
    int stop_s = clock();
    std::cout << std::endl << std::endl << "Executed In: " << (stop_s - start_s) / double(CLOCKS_PER_SEC) << "s\n" << std::endl;

    system("pause");
    return(0);
}

void mergeSort(int arrayToSort[], int startIndex, int lengthToSort) {

    int midIndex = 0;

    if (startIndex < lengthToSort) { // if base case not reached
        midIndex = (startIndex + lengthToSort) / 2;
        mergeSort(arrayToSort, startIndex, midIndex);
        mergeSort(arrayToSort, (midIndex + 1), lengthToSort);
        merge(arrayToSort, startIndex, lengthToSort);
    }
}

void merge(int arraySortedInTwoHalves[], int startIndex, int length) {

    int size = (length - startIndex) + 1;
    int *temp = new int[size]; // temp array to hold elements

    int left = startIndex; // left side of the array
    int midIndex = (startIndex + length) / 2; // border
    int right = midIndex + 1; // right side of the array
    int i = 0;

    while ((left <= midIndex) && (right <= length)) { // while there are elements in both sides...

        if (arraySortedInTwoHalves[left] < arraySortedInTwoHalves[right]) { // add whichever is lower from the appropriate side
            temp[i++] = arraySortedInTwoHalves[left++];
        }
        else {
            temp[i++] = arraySortedInTwoHalves[right++];
        }
    }
    while (left <= midIndex) // if one runs out... 
    {
        temp[i++] = arraySortedInTwoHalves[left++];
    }
    while (right <= length) // if one runs out... 
    {
        temp[i++] = arraySortedInTwoHalves[right++];
    }

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) { // copy elements to the original array
        arraySortedInTwoHalves[startIndex + i] = temp[i]; // startIndex + i because of recursion
    }
    delete []temp; // delete temp array
}
```

Comment: Help readers out: A merge function usually takes two arrays as inputs, which need not necessarily be the same size, so it's not clear how your single-array-and-single-length-taking `merge()` function is *supposed* to work.  Also the very first thing you do inside this function is compute `size = (length - startIndex) + 1`, so `length` didn't mean what I thought it meant.

Comment: Sorry. I should've clarified this better. I have a lab, as a part of the lab, I am given two function signatures; I have to implement functionality without changing the signatures. I have seen methods with two arrays passed as well as low, mid, high passed too, but I can't use that. The the length variable is a bit confusing, I agree, but I was given that and I can't modify it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your bug is here

```
    }
    k++;
    while (i < left) {
        temp[k] = arraySortedInTwoHalves[i];
        k++;
    }
    while (j < length) {
        temp[k] = arraySortedInTwoHalves[j];
        j++;
    }
}
```

This should be

```
    }
    k++;
} //  Moved brace from end to here.

// These two loops should be after the main loop.

while (i < left) {
    temp[k] = arraySortedInTwoHalves[i];
    // You forgot to increment i
    k++;
}
while (j < length) {
    temp[k] = arraySortedInTwoHalves[j];
    j++;
    // You forgot to increment k
}
```

Its hard to tell if there are other errors but I suspect there are more here.

By using the length here (`lengthToSort`).

```
void mergeSort(int arrayToSort[], int startIndex, int lengthToSort) {
```

The point `arrayToSort + lengthToSort` is one past the end. This sort of indicates that you are using the standard C++ idiom of `[begin,end)`.

This next call seems to follow that convention.

```
        mergeSort(arrayToSort, startIndex, midIndex);
```

But this calls seems to indicate that length is inclusive. As you are excluding `midIndex` from the range (which means it should be in the call above). But that means `lengthToSort` should also be in the range below but that is not the implication of the original call.

```
        mergeSort(arrayToSort, (midIndex + 1), lengthToSort);
```

Are your ranges correct? To help make this explicit a lot of implementations make this explicit by using the interface.

```
        mergeSort(begin, mid);  // begin, mid and end are iterators.
        mergeSort(mid, end);
        merge(begin, mid, end);
```

Comment: I don't know if my ranges are correct. I suspect that's what I am having a problem with. I can't figure how to populate the temp array correctly. I've seen a method where the low, mid and high are passed into the function, however I can't change the signature because that's part of the lab. I pass the original length as -1 in the main, so it should be correctly splitting the array.

Comment: @G3ORGE: These may help: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/31726/merge-sort-in-c http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/123976/merge-sort-implementation-efficiency http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/90331/merge-sort-algorithm

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I will take a take a look at those links.

Comment: @G3ORGE: If this answer helped you solve the problem, you should give it an upvote and mark it as the accepted answer.